# Does `DispatchQueue.global().async` make new global queue?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch, dispatch-queue

```swift
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print("A")
}
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print("B")
}
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print("C")
}
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print("D")
}

let a = DispatchQueue.global()

a.async {
    print("A")
}
a.async {
    print("B")
}
a.async {
    print("C")
}
a.async {
    print("D")
}
```

If the global queue is not stored in a variable, the order of A, B, C, D is different each time. 
When the global queue is stored in a variable, A, B, C, and D are called in sequence always(*in a playground). 

I wonder why the code execution results above and below are different.

Are there multiple global queues?

Comment: Never test anything involving threading or memory management in a playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers have discussed the order in which blocks are executed, but I want to directly address your question: “Does `DispatchQueue.global().async` make a new global queue?”

It does not.

We can check empirically by printing the `ObjectIdentifier` of the queue:

```
import Dispatch

let q = DispatchQueue.global()
print(ObjectIdentifier(DispatchQueue.global()))
print(ObjectIdentifier(q))
```

It prints the same `ObjectIdentifier` twice, so both calls to `DispatchQueue.global()` return the same object.

We can also answer the question by looking at the source code. `DispatchQueue.global()` is a Swift wrapper for the C function `dispatch_get_global_queue`. The source is [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/34f383d34450d47dd5bdfdf675fcdaa0d0ec8031/src/init.c#L373):

```
dispatch_queue_global_t
dispatch_get_global_queue(intptr_t priority, uintptr_t flags)
{
    dispatch_assert(countof(_dispatch_root_queues) ==
            DISPATCH_ROOT_QUEUE_COUNT);


    if (flags & ~(unsigned long)DISPATCH_QUEUE_OVERCOMMIT) {
        return DISPATCH_BAD_INPUT;
    }
    dispatch_qos_t qos = _dispatch_qos_from_queue_priority(priority);
#if !HAVE_PTHREAD_WORKQUEUE_QOS
    if (qos == QOS_CLASS_MAINTENANCE) {
        qos = DISPATCH_QOS_BACKGROUND;
    } else if (qos == QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE) {
        qos = DISPATCH_QOS_USER_INITIATED;
    }
#endif
    if (qos == DISPATCH_QOS_UNSPECIFIED) {
        return DISPATCH_BAD_INPUT;
    }
    return _dispatch_get_root_queue(qos, flags & DISPATCH_QUEUE_OVERCOMMIT);
}
```

It calls `_dispatch_get_root_queue`. The source for that is [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/34f383d34450d47dd5bdfdf675fcdaa0d0ec8031/src/inline_internal.h#L1890):

```
DISPATCH_ALWAYS_INLINE DISPATCH_CONST
static inline dispatch_queue_global_t
_dispatch_get_root_queue(dispatch_qos_t qos, bool overcommit)
{
    if (unlikely(qos < DISPATCH_QOS_MIN || qos > DISPATCH_QOS_MAX)) {
        DISPATCH_CLIENT_CRASH(qos, "Corrupted priority");
    }
    return &_dispatch_root_queues[2 * (qos - 1) + overcommit];
}
```

It's just an array lookup, so it returns the same value every time, unless the contents of `_dispatch_root_queues` changes—which it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just a coincidence that they print in the correct order. The docs for `DispatchQueue.global()` say.

> Tasks submitted to the returned queue are scheduled concurrently with respect to one another.
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300077-global#

Since it says they're scheduled concurrently (as opposed to serially), it shouldnt be expected that they'll always print in the same order.

The async tasks also are not really doing anything. I'd suspect there isn't enough variability between them to cause a different order to be printed.

`DispatchQueue.global()` looks like it always returns the same instance based on the memory addresses I'm seeing in a playground. It may be doing something extra under the hood that may be introducing a little bit a variability in the execution time of each async task.

Swapping the order of the of the two tests in your code also produced a different output for me, confirming that the order shouldn't be relied on.

```
A2
C2
D2
B2
A1
B1
C1
D1
```

```swift
let a = DispatchQueue.global()

a.async {
    print("A2")
}
a.async {
    print("B2")
}
a.async {
    print("C2")
}
a.async {
    print("D2")
}

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print("A1")
}
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print("B1")
}
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print("C1")
}
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print("D1")
}
```

Comment: When executed in the playground, they appear in order, but when executed in CLT, it's out of order. Could you explain the difference between both please?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and got:

```
B
B
A
D
A
C
C
D
```

So all 8 print statements are interleaved with one another, not entirely randomly but with no particular pattern either. Earlier print statements tend to execute a bit earlier than later ones, but basically it's unpredictable — it's asynchronous.